# Recursive Formula

Tags: c++, data-structures, recursion

First, yes it's HW - really tried but not sure of something so ill be happy if you will help me:)

I have this code:

```
void func(int A[], int start, int n)
{
    int p = n/2;
    if ( 1 < n )
    {
        func(A, start, p);
        func(A, start + p, n-p);
        for (i=0; i<n; i++)
            cout << A[start+i];
    }
}

func(A, 0, n);
```

I need to give this code a recusive formula.
What I did was - first recursion call is T(n/2).
                 Second - this is the problem! really confuse with adding the 'p'...is that
                 T(n/2) too??
                 Three - for is running on theta(n)
                 and the outside recursion call is T(n)...

Can you help me get to the final formula??

Thanks

Comment: what should it do? what is the problem?

Comment: I need to find the recusive formula ( T(n) = ???)
not sure what to do with second recursive call...

Comment: What about using a "step-by-step example" ?
Try different variables' values and check what's the result for each and one of them

Comment: In the beginning I thought it was running from n/2 to n/2 so theta is(1)... but I think thats wrong...

Comment: Go the other way, start with a call that doesn't recurse. Then look at a call that recurses once. Then a call that recurses twice. By then, you should start to be understanding it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I read it right, you want the recurrence for the run time complexity.

For `n > 1`, you recur with parameter `floor(n/2)` and with parameter `n-floor(n/2)`, and after that you output `n` items. Thus you have

```
T(n) = T(cost of first recursive call) + T(second rec. call) + extra work
```

which you should now bring into a form suitable to apply the master theorem.

Comment: Hi Daniel, that's right..so than I get : T(n/2) + T(n/2) + n ???
just not sure about the second rec call!

Comment: Strictly, you get `T(floor(n/2)) + T(ceiling(n/2)) + n`. If you fudge it to `2*T(n/2) + n`, you should be prepared to justify it (not too hard, first fudge, then use the result of that for the justification).

Answer (score 0):

This is either a trick question or you misread the question. What you have **is** a recursive formula.  Do you need to switch this formula from C++ to more traditional math notation?  Do need to find a non-recursive algorithm?  In your answer to the question, what is T?  The term formula does not really apply here because nothing gets computed.  This is a void function that never modifies the given array.  All that happens is some things elements from the array get put on the screen in some order.

I would start by tracing an example to understand what is going on.
Lets say `A = {1,2,3,4}` Then 'func(A, 0,4)' is:

```
tracing func(A,0,4) :
p = 2
func(A,0,2)
func(A,2,2)
cout  << 1 2 3 4

tracing func(A,0,2) :
p = 1 //start=0; n=2
func(A,0,1)
func(A,1,1)
cout << 1 2

tracing func(A,2,2) :
p = 1 //start=2; n=2
func(A,2,1)
func(A,3,1)
cout << 3 4

tracing func(A,2,1) :
p = 0 //start=0; n=1
func(A,0,0)
func(A,0,1)
cout << 1

tracing func(A,3,1) :
p = 0 //start=3; n=1
func(A,3,0)
func(A,3,1)
cout << 3

tracing func(A,2,1) :
p = 0 //start=0; n=1
func(A,0,0)
func(A,0,1)
cout << 1
```

At this point I'm going to stop because this is your homework problem.  You can finish it from here.